# concatenate strings in a character vector based on element names

Tags: r, string-concatenation

I have a named character vector, `a`,  that I would like to concatenate some of its elements based on their name

```
a <- c('item 1' = 'first_i1', 'item 1' = 'second_i2', 'item 2' = 'only_i2')
a
     item 1      item 1      item 2 
 "first_i1" "second_i2"   "only_i2"
```

expected result using blank space as the separator

```
a_out <- c('item 1' = 'first_i1 second_i2', 'item 2' = 'only_i2')
a_out
              item 1               item 2 
"first_i1 second_i2"            "only_i2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can concatenate with `paste` by using grouping variables as the `names` of the `vector` 'a'

```
tapply(a, names(a), FUN = paste, collapse = ' ')
#            item 1               item 2 
#"first_i1 second_i2"            "only_i2"
```

Comment: @MoeSam  Glad to know that it worked.  Another option is `by` `c(by(a, names(a), FUN = paste, collapse=' '))`

Comment: That works too. Would there be any advantage of using `by` over `tapply` given that `by` is a wrapper for `tapply`? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @MoeSam `by` is sometimes useful to pass multiple columns and process it